# SpriteKit & Swift, Is it possible to use Array's for pooling SKSpritenodes?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Im working on a 2d siderunner game with platforms, obstacles, etc. The platforms are being created then moved from right to left and then removed again. And thats were my problem is, since creating and removing nodes every time is not very efficient i sometimes see an fps drop of 1-3 frames especially when there are more than +15 nodes created. So i considered that pooling nodes is essential for good performance.

Here's what i tried so far:

**Creating global Array variabels:**

```
var smallPlArray = [SKSpriteNode]() 
var midPlArray = [SKSpriteNode]() 
var bigPlArray = [SKSpriteNode]() 
var groundPlArray = [SKSpriteNode]()

// small, middle and big refers to the platforms size's not the array size
```

**Function which creates SKSpritenodes and adds them to the array's:**

```
// Gets called in didMoveToView

func fillSpriteArrays() {

    var smallPlCount:Int = 0
    var groundPlCount:Int = 0

    for _ in 0..<10 {

        let smallPlatform = SKSpriteNode(texture: platform_Small_Texture)
        smallPlatform.zPosition = 4
        smallPlatform.size = CGSize(width: 509.5, height: 55.8)
        smallPlatform.isHidden = true

        smallPlatform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: smallPlatform.size)
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platforms
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
        smallPlatform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

        smallPlArray.append(smallPlatform)
        groundPair.addChild(smallPlArray[smallPlCount])

        smallPlCount += 1
    }


    for _ in 0..<10 {

        let groundPlatform = SKSpriteNode(texture: middle_Ground_Platform_Texture)
        groundPlatform.zPosition = 4
        groundPlatform.size = CGSize(width: 898.4, height: 255.5)
        groundPlatform.isHidden = true

        groundPlatform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: groundPlatform.size)
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.groundPlatform
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
        groundPlatform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

        groundPlArray.append(groundPlatform)
        groundPair.addChild(groundPlArray[groundPlCount])

        groundPlCount += 1
    }

 // Same for the other array's...
}
```

**Attempt to take SKSpritenodes from array and work with them:**

```
func platforms1() {

    let ground1 = groundPlArray[0]
    ground1.position = CGPoint(x: 3800, y: 375)
    ground1.isHidden = false

    let ground2 = groundPlArray[1]
    ground2.position = CGPoint(x: 7000, y: 375)
    ground2.isHidden = false

    let smallPl1 = smallPlArray[0]
    smallPl1.position = CGPoint(x: 4350, y: 720)
    smallPl1.isHidden = false

    let smallPl2 = smallPlArray[1]
    smallPl1.position = CGPoint(x: 5600, y: 720)
    smallPl2.isHidden = false

// Other nodes not in connection with the array's

    createSpring(position: CGPoint(x: 2500, y: 337))
    createCrate(position: CGPoint(x: 5000, y: 350))
    createCrate(position: CGPoint(x: 5600, y: 350))
    createJelly(position: CGPoint(x: 7000, y: 330))
    createRoundWoodSpike(position: CGPoint(x: 7300, y: 550))
    createPlatformEndNode(position: CGPoint(x: 8500, y: 788))
    createDiamond(position: CGPoint(x: 2800, y: 800))
    createDiamond(position: CGPoint(x: 2880, y: 800))
    createDiamond(position: CGPoint(x: 4070, y: 575))
 }
```

So, here's where im failing. Somehow only one node from the smallPlArray gets displayed but on the groundPlArray all two nodes get displayed. The parent of these nodes (groundPair) gets moved and when a certain point is passed (no nodes on screen), the parent position gets resetted and platforms1() gets called again and the nodes come again.
This works for all the other nodes like the spring, crate etc. but the nodes from the array dont come back again. Only when platforms1() is called the first time 3 of the 4 nodes from the array show up. Obviously im failing at this. What am i doing wrong? Is there another or better way of pooling? Unfortunately im not so experienced with array's but i could learn if thats necessary.

**EDIT**

Here's how the code being called:

```
    func diceRollPlatforms() {

    platformSpawnCount = 0

    let shuffled = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 1, highestValue: 15)
    var number = shuffled.nextInt()

// Repeat one platform sequence over and over instead of a random int
    if number != 1 || number == 1 {
        platforms1() 
}
```

Then:

```
func platforms_1() {

    shouldMovePlatforms = true // Just triggers the moving of groundPair in update

    createSpring(position: CGPoint(x: 2500, y: 337))
    createCrate(position: CGPoint(x: 5000, y: 350))
    createCrate(position: CGPoint(x: 5600, y: 350))
    createJelly(position: CGPoint(x: 7000, y: 330))
    createRoundWoodSpike(position: CGPoint(x: 7300, y: 550))
    createPlatformEndNode(position: CGPoint(x: 8500, y: 788)) // On contact with the player,groundPair(parent) gets reseted and diceRollPlatforms() is called again. 
//BUT the children are not removed. Children like spring etc are removed with the physics engine when they contact a node
//on the near outside left of the screen which does not affect the platforms, only obstacles like said before spring, crate...


    let ground1 = groundPlArray[0]
    ground1.position = CGPoint(x: 3800, y: 375)
    ground1.isHidden = false


    let ground2 = groundPlArray[1]
    ground2.position = CGPoint(x: 7000, y: 375)
    ground2.isHidden = false

    let smallPl1 = smallPlArray[0]
    smallPl1.position = CGPoint(x: 4350, y: 720)
    smallPl1.isHidden = false

    let smallPl2 = smallPlArray[1]
    smallPl2.position = CGPoint(x: 5600, y: 720)
    smallPl2.isHidden = false

// How the array is being filled is already explained above
    }
```

Inside of the functions createSpring and others, they are basicly all the same:

```
func createSpring(position: CGPoint) {
    let spring = SKSpriteNode(texture: spring_Texture3)
    spring.size = CGSize(width: 230.9, height: 151.0)
    spring.zPosition = 4
    spring.position = position

    spring.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: spring.size)
    spring.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.spring
    spring.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    spring.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    spring.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    spring.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    spring.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

    groundPair.addChild(spring)
}
```

@Knight0fDragon If something is unclear please let me know.

**SECOND EDIT**

```
    func createPlatformEndNode(position: CGPoint) {
    let platformEndNode = SKSpriteNode()
    platformEndNode.position = position
    platformEndNode.zPosition = 4
    platformEndNode.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 1536)

    platformEndNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: platformEndNode.size)
    platformEndNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platformEndNode
    platformEndNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platforms | PhysicsCatagory.obstacle | PhysicsCatagory.obstacleDeathObject | PhysicsCatagory.enemy | PhysicsCatagory.collidablePlatforms | PhysicsCatagory.spring | PhysicsCatagory.breakAbleObstacle | PhysicsCatagory.triggerEnemyNode | PhysicsCatagory.platformEndNode | PhysicsCatagory.groundPlatform | PhysicsCatagory.collidableGroundPlatform | PhysicsCatagory.breakAblePlatformsNotcollidable | PhysicsCatagory.breakAblePlatforms | PhysicsCatagory.cherry
    platformEndNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    platformEndNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    groundPair.addChild(platformEndNode)
}

func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // Check if contact ended with platformEndNode
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.platformEndNode && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.dragon || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.platformEndNode {
        spawnPlatformsAgain()

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.platformEndNode {
            firstBody.node!.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            secondBody.node!.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
        // Check if contact ended with platformStartNode
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.triggerPlatformStartNode && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.dragon || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.triggerPlatformStartNode {
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.triggerPlatformStartNode {
            firstBody.node!.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            secondBody.node!.removeFromParent()
        }
        if platformSpawnCount == 0 { platformSpawnCount = 1; prepareGroundPair(); diceRollPlatforms() }
    }
}
     func spawnPlatformsAgain() {

    if !wasWaterHere {

        timeToIncreaseGameSpeed = true; platformSpawnCount = 0
        prepareForNextPlatforms(); increaseGameSpeed()
        if addRollingWoodEnemy == true { spawnRollingWoodEnemyAfterPlatforms() }
        isCollidingWithBreakAblePlatforms = false

        createPlatformStartNode(position: CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 768))

    } else {

        timeToIncreaseGameSpeed = true; platformSpawnCount = 0
        prepareForNextPlatforms(); increaseGameSpeed()
        if addRollingWoodEnemy == true { spawnRollingWoodEnemyAfterPlatforms() }
        isCollidingWithBreakAblePlatforms = false

        wasWaterHere = false
        bigGroundAndWaterTileNode.removeAllChildren()
        bigGroundAndWaterTileNode.removeAllActions()
        bigGroundAndWaterTileNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        bigGroundAndWaterTileNode.isHidden = true

        createPlatformStartNode(position: CGPoint(x: 1536, y: 768))
    }
}
    func prepareGroundPair() {

    shouldMovePlatforms = false
    groundPair.position.x = 0
}

func prepareForNextPlatforms() {

    groundPair.position.x = 0

    enemyParent.removeAllChildren(); enemyParent.removeAllActions()
    enemyParent.position.x = 0

}
```

**THIRD EDIT**

Moving of groundPair:

```
    // Runs in Update
func moveWorldObjects() {
            if shouldMovePlatforms == true {
                groundPair.position = CGPoint(x: groundPair.position.x - CGFloat(xPosition), y: groundPair.position.y)
            }
```

}

Comment: Copy and paste fail   `let smallPl2 = smallPlArray[1]
    smallPl1.position = CGPoint(x: 5600, y: 720)
    smallPl2.isHidden = false`  You have a Pl1

Comment: BTW,  this is where background queues can be handy.  If you create you nodes on a background queue, then you will not drop in framerate.  Just make sure you give yourself time to create new platforms. (Like as soon as one is used, create a new one on a background queue)

Comment: Comments are not intended for an extended debugging session; this conversation (and the one on the answer below) has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151416/discussion-on-question-by-icod3r-spritekit-swift-is-it-possible-to-use-array). If there is useful information hidden in there, *please* add it to the question and/or the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, your issue is a copy and paste failure.  You never set the position of smallPl2, instead you set smallPl1 twice by accident.

I would avoid this approach all together though.  Only time I would recommend doing a pool like this is when you are under heavy performance constraints (Which you are not, your code is just not efficient).  Creating a new object gives you a clean slate every time, so you do not need to worry about resetting the properties of your nodes.

Instead, go back to what you were doing, and create a new platform every time.

This time though,  create series of reserved nodes queued on a background thread to accomplish your goal. You can then add them to your scene during the update or didFinish portions of your update phase to avoid any conflicts.

Here is an example of how to create some reserved nodes

```
var reservedNodes = SKNode()  //This SKNode is going to house all of our reserves,  I prefer it over [SKNode]().

func spawnReserves()
{
       if reservedNodes.children.count < 5
       {
          DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async 
          { 
            [weak self] in 
            //before this point if self does not exist then safely exit
            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
           //beyond this point we do not want self to die                
            let node = strongSelf.createNode()
            DispatchQueue.main.async 
            {
              [weak self] in 
              //before this point if self does not exist then safely exit
              //now because we use `node`,  strongSelf should not even be needed, since the background thread should be retained, but I threw it in just in case
              guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
              //beyond this point we do not want self to die
              //As long as reservedNodes is not added to the scene, this should not cause problems, never add it to the scene.
              strongSelf.reservedNodes.addChild(node)
            }
          }
       }

}


func update(currentTime: TimeInterval)
{
    //If I need nodes grab from reserve
    //what is nice about .first is the where feature, so you can say first(where:{$0.isKind(of:PlatformNode)})
    if let node = reserveNodes.children.first
    {
      node.moveToParent(self) //this will remove them from the array for us
    }
}

func didFinishUpdate()
{
   spawnReserves()
}
```

Now with subclassing, you can take this even further and check when children are removed to spawn new ones, so that you always have nodes being created, but I will leave the more advanced work up to you.  This should at least help you conceptually get started with pools